# Extracting text from string in R

Tags: r, string

I have the following string:

```
 x<-"\"stream;\"\" Well done; fans !!\"\";\"\"Boy\""
```

and I am looking for a syntax in R which enables me to extract the `"Well done; fans !!"` from the string. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through `gregexpr` and `regmatches` function.

```
> x<-"\"stream;\"\" Well done; fans !!\"\";\"\"Boy\""
> m <- gregexpr("\"[^\"]*\"", x)
> o <- regmatches(x, m)
> o[[1]][2]
[1] "\" Well done; fans !!\""
```

This  would match  all the double quoted strings and prints only the second value.